# Update property relation with py2neo neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to check if a relation between two nodes exists but i get this error:

> ```
> raise TypeError("Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound") TypeError: Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound
> ```

below my code:

```
graph = Graph(user='neo4j')

src = Node(src_type, internal_id=int(src_id))
dst = Node(dst_type, internal_id=int(dst_id))

src_voted_dst = Relationship(src, "VOTED", dst)

for elem in graph.match(start_node=src, rel_type="VOTED", end_node=dst, bidirectional=True):
    elem.properties["vote"] = elem.properties["vote"] + 1
    elem.push()
    break
else:
    src_voted_dst.properties["vote"] = 1
    graph.merge(src_voted_dst)
```

Comment: Which line cause error?

Comment: it is raised by match function: for elem in graph.match(start_node=src, rel_type="VOTED", end_node=dst, bidirectional=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code:

```
src = Node(src_type, internal_id=int(src_id))
dst = Node(dst_type, internal_id=int(dst_id))
```

src and dst are created locally, but not bound to these nodes in the database. 
Bind the local nodes to the database with merge:

```
db_src = graph.merge(src)
db_dst = graph.merge(dst)
```

Then match should then work:

```
for elem in graph.match(db_src, "VOTED", db_dst)
```

(note that elem.properties["vote"] will not work, there should be something link elem.start_node()["vote"] or elem.end_node()["vote"])